# Calculating Interest Expense with amortization

Tags: calculation

Preface: I'm an engineer not an accountant so all this finical modeling stuff is new to me.

I've been given the task to take an existing finical model in Excel and put it into a jupyter notebook. One of steps along the way to calculate XIRR is calculating interest expense for a given period. The issue I am running into is that there is a circular reference between Interest Expense and Amortization that is solved iteratively in excel that I want to solve algorithmically in my notebook.

The cell formulas is as follows:

- x = Interest Expense
- S = Starting Balance
- A = Amortization
- R =Interest Rate
- E = EBITDA
- DSCR = 1.3

X = AVERAGE(S, S-A) * R

A = (E/1.3) - X

Comment: How are you using this for personal finance or say not a class assignment?

Comment: If they are solving it iteratively, the closed form -- if here is one -- is almost certainly an integral or worse. How's your calculus?